# Vue.js : How can I do native events handling of child component from parent component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component that wraps an anchor:

```
Vue.component('wrapper-link', {
    template : `
        <div>
            <a href="xxx" v-on="$listeners">text link</a>
        <div>
    `
});
```

I'm using it like this in my app:

*template:*

```
<div id="app">
    <wrapper-link @click.stop="onClickEvent"></wrapper-link>
</div>
```

*script:*

```
let app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    methods: {
        onClickEvent() {
            console.log('clicked');
        }
    }
})
```

I was expecting that after clicking `text link`, the native `click`-event would be blocked and the console would log 'clicked'; but none of that happened. The native click event worked (navigation occurred).

I know of `event.preventDefault()`, but I want to use Vue's event modifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the `.stop` event modifier (calls [`event.stopImmediatePropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopImmediatePropagation)), but the behavior you're seeking is accomplished with `.prevent` (calls [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)):

```
<wrapper-link @click.prevent="onClickEvent" />
```

```js
Vue.component('wrapper-link', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <a href="http://google.com"
         target="_blank"
         v-on="$listeners">Google</a>
    </div>
  `
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    onClick(e) {
      console.log('click');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17"></script>

<div id="app">
  <wrapper-link @click.prevent="onClick" />
</div>
```